# Регулярные выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, методы

```
    public static void date(String s){
        Pattern p =Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}+.\\d{1,2}+.\\d{4}+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
```

Есть такой метод он находит дату рождения в тексте но мне нужно сделать условие по которому можно задавать в первое значение от 1-31 второе условие 1-12. В моём примере если я в первое значение задаю 341 то оно отобразит только 41

Answer (score 3):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужен вот такой монстр:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

Первая группа- это день 01-31, вторая группа-это месяц 01-12

Comment: Можешь объяснить как оно работает ?

Comment: 2 группы: Первая ищет числа, а вторая месяца. Используется оператор | или. Каждый нацелен на определенный числовой вариант. Например,  если у нас число до 10, то первым числом будет 0, а второе числое начинается с 1 и до 9.

Comment: Если нам нужно число 20 то нам нужно несколько раз задать от 0 до 9

Comment: Если нужно точное совпадение 20 найти, то [2][0] .На вики неплохой учебник лежит https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F